# A better algorithm for this code

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

```
public class twoSumProblem {
public static int bruteForce(Integer[] a) {
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
for (int j = i+1; j < a.length; j++) if (a[i] + a[j] == 0) count++;
return count;
}
```

How can i propose a better algorithm for this code? Also i need their running times complexity. Please help me.

Comment: Take a look at [help/on-topic] and [ask]

Comment: If you want to fix an algorithm, first understand how it works. Describe the function that it computes in terms that you understand yourself.

Comment: If you can find the complexity of your algorithm, add it to your question. Then you would be able to judge which algorithm is better. If you do not know how to find the complexity of the algorithm, you probably need a super quick course in Algorithm Theory.

Comment: Hint: Once you know `a[i]`, you know what value would produce a sum of `0`. Do you know of a data structure that provides fast lookup, or a way to restructure your array so you can quickly check whether a certain value in in it?

Answer (score 1):

### Introduction

Ordering the array you gain the advantage to control only the numbers lower or equal to zero.
In fact, considering the i-th element of the ordered array, you have three cases

- **a[ i ]< 0  :** the match(es) will be with the element(s) of value equal to the *absolute value* of a[i], with index higher than i.
- **a[i] ==0 :** the match(es) will be only with element(s) equal to zero.
- **a[i]>0 :** this case won't have any matches. In fact a positive number can match only his *additive inverse*, but these element have already been controlled in the previous steps.

### The algorithm pseudocode

```
int countPairs(Integer[] a) {
   a=quicksort(a); //return the ordered array
   int count,i=0;
   int index=a.lenght;
   int current;
   while(a[i]<=0 && i<a.lenght){
       current=abs(a[i]);
       while( a[index]>=current){
            if(a[index]==current){
               count++;
            }          
        index--;
       }
       i++;
   }
  return count;
}
```

### Complexity

Put **n = a.lenght**,the ordering process needs O(n*log n), so:

- **WORST CASE :O(n*log(n))**
  Searching for the pairs require a complexity O(n). This case corresponds to the situation where the array is exclusively composed by negative values.
- **MID CASE :O(n*log(n))**
  The mid case has asymptotically the same complexity, but the explored value will be less than n because of the presence of positive numbers.
- **BETTER CASE Θ(n*log(n)**
  It occurs when the array has only positive elements, so there is no matcht and the searching process terminate immediately. So the complexity is due only to the ordering process.